# How to create Datadog spanner for bigquery

Tags: go, google-bigquery, datadog

we're using Datadog to collect APMs.
for AWS calls, Datadog provides an HTTP wrapper. All is ok with HTTP calls and AWS HTTP wrapper.
the problem is with Bigquery, we are using [this library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/tree/main/bigquery) to connect to the database,

```
c, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "my-project-ID")
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}
```

it's not just HTTP client and I couldn't wrap it like aws. ( inside of it uses the http client but it's another thing)

I tried to create a span manually but it's just considered as a nested span which is not ideal with the following code.

```
var span tracer.Span
span, ctx = tracer.StartSpanFromContext(ctx, "bigquery", tracer.ResourceName("name"))
defer span.Finish()
```

my question is that, how Bigquery calls could be traced in the Datadog?

Comment: Did you try adding additional tracer options?  `[]tracer.StartSpanOption{...}` and add something like the details of your BigQuery calls?  There isn't a direct integration from Datadog for Bigquery from what I can tell, so you won't get all of the tracing "for free" like you would get in other Datadog supported DBs (MySQL, Postgres, etc.). https://docs.datadoghq.com/database_monitoring/architecture/

Comment: @adam2k Thank you for your attention, for that time I just remembered I created a custom span that does not contain DB transaction details. but it was better than nothing

Comment: I was able to test this out yesterday and if you use the `spanType: sql` and then add a custom tag for `sql.command` you can drop in your SQL command for the value and it should do what you need.  Datadog will parse out that custom field in their UI.